# Clear activity stack before launching another activity

Tags: android, activity-stack

Hi there (my first question here ;-)

There might be similar questions but none of them seem to answer my question or gives me a real solution...

---

*Problem*
`A` (root) starts `B`. `B` can start other activities. `A` decides to dismiss the stack (network connection loss) and start `C`. This seems to be a drastic decision but the user would expect that and that really makes sense in this case...

*Question*
How to do that? I would expect using a certain flag or just call something like `dismissStack`. But I can't find the *right* solution (see research below).

*Research*
I read a lot of documentation but the available flags don't match my needs (or I didn't understand it right). Other answers out there tell me to remember the started activities (e.g. in an array) and finish them when needed. But this seems dirty to me and somehow I can't accept that to be the right solution. There must be something cleaner I hope?!
(Storing the stack seems even wrong to me. Your app can be killed by the system, so your static data, but your history will be loaded again on startup. So you would have to persist your saved stack. This gets even dirtier...)

**Update**
My code and what I have tried (abstracted):

```
// in A
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, B.class), REQUEST_B);

// network fail in A
// setting any flags on C has no influence
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, C.class), REQUEST_C);
```

([FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) is no solution, please read the documentation...)

I press <kbd>Back</kbd> on `C` and `B` still pops up and is so still there...

I can remove the activity by calling `finishActivity(REQUEST_B)`. But when `B` started another activity `D` it will still pop up if I hit <kbd>Back</kbd> on `C` later. `B` is gone but `D` is still there...

---

I'm sure there is something I didn't understand yet or just missed. Can someone give me a hint or approve my research if it has to be really that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I got so far and it works pretty good:

Use `startActivityForResult`. Create a dummy request code if you actually don't need to wait for a result. Then do this in `onDestroy` of every activity.

```
if (isFinishing()) {
    finishActivity(REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

For example: You have `A, B, C, D` on the stack, call `finishActivity(REQUEST_B)` from `A`, this will chain the `onDestroy` calls so `B` kills `C` and `C` kills `D`.

---

That's the best solution I can think of. Other solutions out there are messing with the activity lifecycle and/or are error prone.

I still hope there's a cleaner way...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag to be used with your intents.

From the documentation at the link above, an example is provided:

> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

You can see more about Tasks and the Backstack in Android at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks) in the Android Dev Docs

Comment: There was an answer before. I assume that the author deleted it since this doesn't apply in my case. This flag clears to the activity in the stack when it was started before. So when I have `A, B, C, D` and start `E` from `A` it has no effect at all... Thank you anyway! ;-)

Comment: @Knickedi Will there only ever be one instance of A? If so, and I recognize that it may be a little cumbersome, then when you realize you want to clear the stack on top of B, you could send an intent from B to A with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP set, and that would remove B through D (assuming they are the stack built on top of B). To ensure A only has one isntance, you can use the `android:launchMode="singleTask" (or singleInstance).

Comment: That's an interesting idea. It would rely on the fact that `B` is expecting to be closed by `A`. `B` itself will never know that `A` is about to start another activity. I can think of an cleaner approach (*hack*) and will post it here after testing when there's no better solution...

Comment: @Knickedi Suppose then that you had an interface defined in A with a single method. B (and any other class) could implement this interface and the single method. That way, when A wants B to close the stack on top of it, it would call the method ClassB.nameOfMethod(), which would trigger B to send the aforementioned intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both the flags for new task and clear task to clear all previous activities from the stack

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```